# Spring @ComponentScan exclude/include filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

As a good practice in a Spring MVC application, the Web configuration should pick up only the "front-end" components, such as `@Controller` or `@RestController`.
Every other bean should be picked up by the Root application context.

I've defined the Web configuration as follow (keep in mind I don't need the `@EnableMvc` annotation, as it extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = { ... },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = @Filter({
                Controller.class,
                ControllerAdvice.class}))
```

And the Root configuration as follows.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = { ... },
        excludeFilters = @Filter({
                Controller.class,
                ControllerAdvice.class}))
```

I've defined two `@RestControllerAdvice` classes, the first one catches all generic `Exception`(s), the second one catches a more specific `ServiceException`.

When throwing a `ServiceException`, the specific adviser is never called, instead only the generic one is picked. Base packages are the same in both configuration classes.

Do I need to specify also `RestControllerAdvice` on the exclude and include filters? Or am I missing something else?

Edit:

Both `@RestControllerAdvice` are without `basePackeges` or any specific criteria.
And the `ServiceException` one is actually found and registered.

If I move the exception handler to the working handler than it is called.
This is how I got it working. If I move the `ServiceException` handler in a separate class it is no more invoked.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalRestControllerAdviser extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(
            final BindException ex,
            final HttpHeaders headers,
            final HttpStatus status,
            final WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
                buildPresentableError(ex.getAllErrors().get(0)),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
    protected Response<?> handleServiceException(final ServiceException e) {
        ...
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleGenericException(final Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Seems like the most generic `ExceptionHandler` is overriding the more specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes are ordered, which means that if Spring internals find an `@ExceptionHandler` which accepts the thrown exception, it will use that one and stop.

When having multiple classes it is possible to set the bean priority with `@Order` (for example). Annotating the `ServiceException` containing class with `@Order` made it working.

Also, based on this feature request https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8881 we can specify multiple classes on one `@Filter` annotation, no need to split them in multiple `@Filter`(s).

Answer (score 5):

Almost there, use the [`FilterType type`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FilterType.html) and separate the filters.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = { ... },
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=Controller.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=ControllerAdvice.class)
    }
)
```

Alternatively, I suggest you create a custom annotation (ex. `@FrontEnd`) and apply the filter to it.

Comment: But why ASSIGNABLE_TYPE? Isn't the right FilterType ANNOTATION?

Comment: Then you can remove it as ANNOTATION is its default value. I'm going to try now splitting filters

Comment: Right. I always explicitly use `FilterType` since I combine the types for sake of readability.

Comment: Nope, seems splitting filters in not working. The ControllerAdvice is picked up, I see it in the logs. So strange

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Have you tried to introduce a custom annotation as an alternative way?

Comment: No, I'd leave this as last resort. I prefer understanding why this is happening.
Btw, both Advisers are without base packages. So they're global, and moving the ExceptionHandler to the one recognized make it works